# GUI for navigating fields in a struct in Octave?

Tags: linux, user-interface, math, matlab, octave

I've been looking around for the last few days and can't seem to find a GUI in Octave (under Linux) that's similar to Matlab's Workspace Browser and Variable Editor GUIs (See matlab docs for examples: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f1-22735.html).

I understand that I can navigate the structures using who/whos commands and then dive into them layer by layer but what I really want is a way to accomplish this from a GUI on my Linux box. I've tried using qtoctave and that's nice, but there doesn't appear to be a way to navigate variables within that app either.

Thus far I've tried the following without success:

- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3523-structbrowser
  (didn't work under octave)
- http://qtoctave.wordpress.com/ (doesn't appear to provide a gui for navigating variables)

Comment: Did you mean variables like structs with several fields, that are "complicated"? Because complex variables in the title is misleading, and I came in here to answer something about `z=x+iy`.

Comment: Yes I meant complex structs. Thanks for clarifying this in my title!

Comment: @sim, I'm afraid I don't have an answer for you... but perhaps you could help answer my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512743/display-struct-fields-without-the-mess).

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at X octave?

http://xoctave.webs.com/

It looks promising. See [this screenshot](http://xoctave.webs.com/apps/photos/photo?photoid=55077643), for example.

Comment: I couldn't find a package available for my distro (Fedora 14) on my hardware, x86_64. It looks to be only available on 32bit hardware, though this link showed how to potentially re-compile it for 64bit: http://xoctave.webs.com/apps/forums/topics/show/1371273-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-9-4. 

Even the source code was a bit tricky to find, the link on the main site is busted. Tracked it down here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xoctave/files/Source/.

Hasn't been updated since 2009 from what I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/domainmath/
- https://sites.google.com/site/domainmathide/

DomainMath IDE has workspace and variable viewer like Matlab.

[image]